# Out of stock product redirects in login panel of magento

Tags: product, stock

How to avoid out of Stock products to redirect visitors on the login page of magento

**Update**

On my Website the products are available even though they are out of stock and when a user clicks on them, it redirects them to the login page.

For Example: I am a user of this website. I want to buy a product : Sugar. 
When i click on "sugar" this redirects me directly at the admin panel login page of magento.

the configuration from the admin panel is :Admin >> System >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Inventory >> Stock Options Display Out of Stock product -> No

but still they are on website. How to give users a 404 error page in this case?

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: please provide more information on your issue.

Comment: On WEbsite the products are  available  even thought they are out of stock and when user click on them, it redirects into login page. For Example. I am a user of this website. I want to buy a product : Sugar. i  When i click on "sugar"  this redirects me directly at the admin panel login page of magento. the configuration from the admin panel is :Admin >> System >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Inventory >> Stock Options
Display Out of Stock product -> No .but still they are on website. How to give users a 404 error page in this case?

Comment: If you enable this setting  then magento  are  remove put of products   from **frontend View ** .And if you want to see this product then it will redirect 404. It  is magento feature

Answer (score 0):

To prevent out of stock items (or any items for that matter) from displaying on the website at all, you must disable the individual product.

Failing to do so will still allow visitors to see the product page.

In order to force any item to redirect to a 404 page, do the following:

**Magento -> Admin -> Catalog -> Products -> SET STATUS TO "DISABLED"**

There are 3 primary best practice methods of doing this:

1. **Do it manually, as explained above**
2. **Utilize the API or CSV import to set status to disabled when/if you update inventory from an external source (like your ERP)**
3. **Do it programmatically, using a method similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406346/magento-set-product-status-to-disabled-when-qty-0-out-of-stock)**